# SQL: How to get the total count from second table on the first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a sql query which does the total count, finds the distinct value and show the foreign key.

example:

```
    : Table 1 :
ID |   ADDRESS.  |LD
____________________________
1  |123 ABC road | 1  
2  |123 ABC road | 1  
3  |123 ABC road | 1  
4  |456 DEF road | 1  
5  |456 DEF road | 2  
6  |456 DEF road | 2  
7  |789 GHI road | 2  
8  |789 GHI road | 3  
9  |987 JKL road | 4  
10 |987 JKL road | 4
```

---

```
     : OUTPUT : 

Count|   ADDRESS.  |LD
____________________________
3    |123 ABC road | 1  
3    |456 DEF road | 2  
2    |789 GHI road | 3  
2    |987 JKL road | 4
```

4 ROWS

Comment: This doesn't *look* like *trying*

Comment: You'll probably need to explain the problem a bit more. For example, when `789 GHI Road` has one LD value of 2 and one of 3, why does only 3 show up in the result? Also, did you try anything at all before asking?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , i tried so many things, however i am not getting the desired results. I tried Select Count(distinct(address))) grouping and without the grouping and many other things

Comment: but there was not luck at all. I am not getting any results unfortunately

Comment: what is the LD column for? when grouping what is the logic behind its data changing?

Comment: LD columns are used for Zones. So the logic is when, we fetch the records from the database, it should show that in zone 1; total count is 4 and show the addresses only once. No repeated addresses. In this case, 123 ABC road and 456 EFG road once

Comment: @SarahMalik , I've answered check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(address), address,max(LD) as LD from Table 1
group by address
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below,**

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ADDRESS, LD FROM Table_1
GROUP BY ADDRESS, LD
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Let me know If this work for you!